# Javafx timeline animation

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to build a snake game. I am able to show my snake to the screen as an array of squares, but now I am not able to animate the movement of my snake.

here is my move method:

```
public void move() {
    // Updates the snake's tail using the snakeBody ArrayList.
    if (tailLength > 0) {
        for (int i = tailLength - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            snakeBody.get(i).x = snakeBody.get(i - 1).x;
            snakeBody.get(i).y = snakeBody.get(i - 1).y;
        }

        snakeBody.get(0).x = x;
        snakeBody.get(0).y =y;
    }

    // Updates the snake's position based on its speed.
    x = x + dx * START_SIZE;
    y = y + dy * START_SIZE;
```

in my controller class I have created an animate method:

```
public void animate() { 
    setFocusTraversable(true);
    setOnKeyPressed(e -> control(e));
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000), e -> snake.move());
    animation = new Timeline(frame);
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
    animation.play();
}
```

here is what my control method looks like:

```
public void control(KeyEvent event) {
    event.getCode();

    if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.A || event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)) {
        snake.setMoving(Direction.LEFT);
    }
    else if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.D || event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
        snake.setMoving(Direction.RIGHT);
    }
    else if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.W || event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)) {
         snake.setMoving(Direction.UP);
    } 
    else if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.S || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN)) {
         snake.setMoving(Direction.DOWN);
    }
    else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        if (over) {
            animation.stop();
        } else {
            animation.pause();
            paused = !paused;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I can do to make an array of square animate on the gamescreen

Comment: what's the initial values of tailLength and i variables please

Comment: private int tailLength;

Comment: try adding animation.setAutoReverse(true);

Comment: yes, I have done that, but my snake doesn't move. I am not sure what I can do. It is stuck at it's start position and when i draw my snake it's start size is 20squares

Comment: There are no `Node`s that provide access to `x` and/or `y` fields and updating fields won't trigger any update unless you go through those values and read them after the `move` code is executed.